# OpenGL - Objects moving in random direction

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I'm making a 2D Videogame using OpenGL and C but I'm facing some troubles. I'm trying to make a certain number objects, let's say 100, roam around with random velocity and direction, but it doesn't work and I'm sure there's a better way of doing this but I can't figure it out.

So far this is my class for the thing I want to be drawn 100 times:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#ifndef _THING_H
#define _THING_H

class thingClase {
public:
    float ypos, xpos, zpos;
    float count;
    thingClase() {
        xpos = rand()%80;
        ypos = rand()%80;
        zpos = 1;
        count = 1;
    }
    };

thingClase thing[100];
int thingNum = 0;
int thingTotal = 100;
int width = 1;
bool alive;

#endif  /* _THING_H */
```

And my main function includes this:

```
void drawThing() {
for (thingNum = 0; thingNum < thingTotal; thingNum++) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(thing[thingNum].xpos, thing[thingNum].ypos, thing[thingNum].zpos);
    glPopMatrix();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I see you are setting up a transformation to draw something:

```
void drawThing() {

// EDIT:
//
// Set the matrix mode!
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

for (thingNum = 0; thingNum < thingTotal; thingNum++) {

    // Yes, good, matrix is saved!
    glPushMatrix();

    // Yes, translate to the thing's position
    glTranslated(thing[thingNum].xpos, thing[thingNum].ypos, thing[thingNum].zpos);

    // Draw the thing here!
    //
    // You know, like call a display list or something.

    // Restore the matrix, also good!
    glPopMatrix();
}
}
```

You need to have a thing to draw. So, if you are using old, easier-to-use OpenGL, make a display list or use `glBegin` and `glEnd`.

Then, after you are comfortable, make and use VBOs and shaders, as that is the way we OpenGL today.